# SSIS Union All - is there a bug in SSIS for this item?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, ssis

I am using SQL 2005 and SSIS

I have 2 data sources.

One from table A and one from table B. I want to move data from table A to table B. But first i get the MAX date from both and compare them. If they are the same then i must either stop the SSIS package or use the Conditional Split.

But when the MAX date from table B go through the Union ALL it become blank!

Any idea why?

Answer (score 2):

Union All transforms do not change the data that comes into them. Check carefully and make sure that the output column for "maxdate" has both "maxdate" columns coming into it. Also check the data types for both.

In fact, I suggest you delete the row with "maxdate" and then add it again, making sure it is correctly set from both inputs.